# Error-Creation of node in Private Ethereum Chain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am trying to create node in Private Ethereum Chain.

l have used this command for creation of Ethereum node:-

```
  geth --datadir="~/data/node1"  init="/Documents/PRIVATENET/genesis.json" –nodiscover --ipcdisable --networkid 100 --port 30301 --rpcport 8101 console
```

I have specified networkid and custom genesis file for creation in the command.But the output shows that,it directs towards the default genesis file and default network id '1'.

(Refer these lines

```
     I1209 13:48:24.553115 eth/backend.go:189] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 1

     I1209 13:48:25.092896 eth/backend.go:207] WARNING: Wrote default ethereum genesis block)
```

This is the output :-

```
 I1209 13:48:24.479719 cmd/utils/flags.go:624] WARNING: No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
 I1209 13:48:24.479972 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/toshiba/data/node1/geth/chaindata
 I1209 13:48:24.531343 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/toshiba/data/node1/geth/chaindata
 I1209 13:48:24.532522 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.4-stable-b70acf3c/linux/go1.7.3
 I1209 13:48:24.532569 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/toshiba/data/node1/geth/chaindata
 I1209 13:48:24.553115 eth/backend.go:189] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 1
 I1209 13:48:25.092896 eth/backend.go:207] WARNING: Wrote default ethereum genesis block
 I1209 13:48:25.093089 eth/backend.go:217] Chain config: {ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000}
 I1209 13:48:25.093502 core/blockchain.go:219] Last header: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
 I1209 13:48:25.093538 core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
 I1209 13:48:25.093573 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
 I1209 13:48:25.094619 p2p/server.go:342] Starting Server
 I1209 13:48:27.245136 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening, enode://65436e03004806bd4f4fc9a131c022c32a6cd2dcdd2773a1a13e03475295fbec6913070b843e756f06d1cf2847808f02ae712aefe93a439ddaaae7bdbcaba88e@[::]:30303
 I1209 13:48:27.246387 p2p/server.go:610] Listening on [::]:30303
 I1209 13:48:27.255301 node/node.go:341] IPC endpoint opened: /home/toshiba/data/node1/geth.ipc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is caused by genesis file in your command use `init path/genesis.json` not `init=path/genesis.json`

Comment: But now it exists with the following error  "flag provided but not defined: -ipcdisable"

Comment: try  --nodiscover not  -nodiscover

Comment: I have tried this                                                                                  ( geth --datadir="~/data/node1"  init "/Documents/PRIVATENET/genesis.json" --nodiscover --ipcdisable --networkid 100 --port 30301 --rpcport 8101 console       )                                                                                                                    but the following error is generated "flag provided but not defined: -nodiscover"

Comment: check your init path

Comment: path specified for genesis.json file is correct

Comment: I have tried this command   geth --datadir="~/data/node1"  init="/Documents/PRIVATENET/genesis.json" --nodiscover --ipcdisable --networkid=5 --port 30301 --rpcport 8101 console to create private network but the network is created with networkid 1.                                        How to connect to another networkid??

Comment: specify your  --networkid 111